# Подравнять элементы на сетке

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, grid

необходимо выровнять несколько элементов горизонтально

```
<Grid HeightRequest="60"
      BackgroundColor="Red">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                 Spacing="0"
                 Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Text="FROM"
               BackgroundColor="Green" />
        <DatePicker Format="D"
                    BackgroundColor="Aqua">
            <DatePicker.Effects>
                <effects:PointerEffect />
            </DatePicker.Effects>
        </DatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                 Spacing="0"
                 Grid.Column="1">
        <Label Text="UNTIL"
               BackgroundColor="Chocolate" />
        <DatePicker Format="D"
                    BackgroundColor="Beige">
            <DatePicker.Effects>
                <effects:PointerEffect />
            </DatePicker.Effects>
        </DatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
    <SearchBar Placeholder="SEARCH..."
               BackgroundColor="Black"
               Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

НУЖНО
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ДАННЫЙ МОМЕНТ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятен ваш вопрос. Заголовок говорит про дизайн на одной линии, в теле у вас вообще разговор про размер. Вы уж определитесь, что хотите. Если так, как на картинке, то это вам нужна сетка, где 2 будут иметь разный размер, а оставшаяся допустим треть от остальных.

Comment: в моем понятии xaml это часть дизайна для мобильного приложения, и да, на примере ниже, то, что мне необходимо, и возможно ли без сетки(grid), а лишь вставить в ContentPage вверху страницы StackLayout и добавить эллементы как на картинке // так как ниже на странице будет некий список, который соответственно фильтруется в зависимости от данного фильтра, но это техническая сторона, которая в данном вопросе не рассматривается. Заранее Благодарна

Comment: При чем тут мобильное приложение? XAML - это язык разметки на котором пишут дизайн, да, без разницы что это, мобильное, десктопное или еще что. Вы пишете дизайн, так пишите его правильно, а не кастрированными методами. Любой дизайн состоит из кучи элементов, которые также могут быть вложены друг в друга. В вашем случае у вас есть `StackLayout` в котором надо разместить правильно объекты, а правильней будет использовать сетку!

Comment: Вопрос изменен, если у кого есть решение, подскажите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решила таким образом через FlexLayout и при изменении экрана эллементы становятся один за другим в столбик (адаптивно)

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row"
            Wrap="Wrap"
            AlignItems="Start"
            JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                 Spacing="0"
                 Margin="8">
        <Label Text="From"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <DatePicker Date="{Binding DateFrom}"
                    FontSize="Micro"
                    Format="D"
                    Grid.Column="1">
        </DatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                 Spacing="0"
                 Margin="8">
        <Label Text="From"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        <DatePicker Date="{Binding DateTo}"
                    FontSize="Micro"
                    Format="D"
                    Grid.Column="1">
        </DatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                 FlexLayout.AlignSelf="End"
                 WidthRequest="332"
                 Margin="8">
        <SearchBar Placeholder="Search..."
                   Text="{Binding Search}" />
    </StackLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name="Filter"
      HeightRequest="80">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="Calendar"
          HeightRequest="80"
          Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="StartDate"
              HeightRequest="80"
              Grid.Column="0"
              HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Du"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <DatePicker Grid.Column="1">
                <DatePicker.Effects>
                    <effects:PointerEffect />
                </DatePicker.Effects>
            </DatePicker>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="EndDate"
              HeightRequest="80"
              Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Au"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <DatePicker BackgroundColor="Red"
                        CharacterSpacing="0"
                        FontSize="Micro"
                        Format="D"
                        Grid.Column="1">
                <DatePicker.Effects>
                    <effects:PointerEffect />
                </DatePicker.Effects>
            </DatePicker>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <SearchBar Placeholder="Search..."
               Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

возможное некое решение, при развернутом экране, но если уменьшить размер экрана, то картинка портится

[image: развернутый экран]

[image: уменьшенный экран]